# WebService(WebApi) and Console C# to access it, getting error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0

I'm trying to create a web api to send data to a database and receive other info. My web api will be in the center of 2 different application that i doesn't own!

But when I try to reach my WebApi from a console application, I'm always getting the

> "(500) Internal Server Error."

So here is my code and my class  (At the moment I'm practicing in a fake project to get experience)

BTW I use   .Net 4 (not 4.5)

Everything is in a Big project and separated with solution that I will say with each class

Solution : DataModel

Class : Permission

```
public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Solution : WebService

Class : PermissionController : ApiController

```
public class PermissionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get([FromUri] int id)
    {
        Permission permission = PermissionDal.GetPermissionById(id);

        if (permission == null)
        {
            return new { Success = Dal.Error };
        }

        return new { Success = Dal.Done, Permission = permission };
    }
}
```

Solution : DataAccess

Class : PermissionDal

```
public static class PermissionDal
{
     public static Permission GetPermissionById(int id)
     {
         return (from p in db.DbPermission where p.PermissionId == id select p).FirstOrDefault();
     }
}
```

Solution : Console

Class : Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Clear();
        client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
        string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:50171/api/Permission?id=1");

        Console.WriteLine(result);
     }
}
```

My webservice solution is really running on port 50171 from the visual studio properties of the project WebService.

I tried

```
string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:50171/api/Permission/1");
```

I tried

```
string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:50171/api/permission?id=1");
```

I tried

```
string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:50171/api/permission/1");
```

I'm always getting the same error.

Comment: Why do you change headers when you request to download a string? Please comment those 2 lines out. And can you actually request the result in your browser manually?

Comment: Can you include the error details?

Comment: i found my problem but i dont know how to solve it! The problem is Entity Framework! cause i tried the same project in 1 solution and only my console project in different project. Everything work fine. The problem is due to my App not knowing the datacontract between the modals and my DataAccessLayer. I will work around and check how to generate the contract between the solutions or only put the modals in the DataAccessLayer solution.